Executable program override a method
I have created an executable, that linked against a static library.
But I want to create another program, that changes behavior of 1 method that defined in this lib without recompilation. I cannot use LD_PRELOAD, since it is not a Shared Library.
For example:

App1 -> StaticLib1:
void DoSmth() { ... original behavior ... }

Lib2 (Static or Dynamic):
void DoSmth() { ... override behavior... }

App2: Launches App1 and causes a method from the Lib2 to be called instead of StaticLib1.


Any ideas how to implement it? Is it possible?
Platform: Linux

What you describe is not how executable and libraries work. You need a different approach.  For instance, by having App2 pass a parameter to App1 when running it, and then App1 can decide which behavior to invoke based on that parameter.

"since it is not a Shared Library." What is not a shared library?

The key thing your need to implement to be able to override across multiple libraries the same class method is ensuring that the default implementation is virtual and then subsequent child classes override the default implementation
Say you have app.h
class App { virtual void DoSmth(){ // Default }};

Then in libraries where you want to change the default implementation in your, for example app2.h
class App2 : public App { void DoSmth() override { // Overridden }};

How this is called is up to you but as long as your classes are linked this way then you could call either the default or the overridden method like so
App* app = new App();
App* app2 = new App2();
app->DoSmth();
app2->DoSmth();
